# Object empty check not working in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I try to push the rank value inside the array if it is not empty. But i cannot check the empty value.

```
Array Data 
0: {name: 0, age: 58, dob: "", mark1: 63, mark2: 43}
1: " "
2: " "
3: " "
4: " "
5: " "
6: " "
```

if object is empty  it should not enter into if loop,right now Loops enter into all the 6 objects.

```
for (let j = 0; j <= 6; j++) 
    {

        if(rankData[j] !==undefined &&  rankData[j] !==" " &&   (Object.keys(rankData[j]).length)!== 0 &&
        rankData[j] !=='undefined' &&  rankData[j] !=='undefined-undefined' )
        { 
            rankData[j].rank = J;
        }
    }
```

If object is not empty is should push the rank value . But right now even object is empty it enter into if loop and show error in this line `rankData[j].rank = J;`

Comment: What is the `rank value` in your case? Check if the array has an empty string? It's hard to understand what you need, please reformulate

Comment: The loop will happen every time, are you saying the code inside the `if` is run every time? (Also, you have a typo, `raknData`)

Comment: @DBS : yes,even empty object it goes inside the loop.

Comment: JS and Typescript are case sensitive languages, did you mean `rankData[j].rank = j;`? Also, if you see errors, please include them in the question, they are generally the most important piece of information about a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to check whether element of an array satisfies the condition. If the condition is satisfied, then assign some value to `rank` property:

```js
let arr = [
    { name: 0, age: 58, dob: "", mark1: 63, mark2: 43 }
    , " "
    , " "
    , " "
    , " "
    , " "
    , " "
];

for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {    
    let elem = arr[index];
    if (Object.keys(elem).length > 0 && typeof elem != 'string' && elem) {
        elem.rank = index;
        console.log(elem);
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check weather some given “something” Is empty you can use this function that I once found on internet.

```js
function isEmpty (value) {
   if (typeof value === “undefined”) return true;
   if (value === null) return true;
   if (typeof value === “string” && value.trim().length === 0) return true;
    if (Array.isArray(value).length === 0) return true;
   if (typeof value === “object” && Object.keys(value).length === 0) return true

  // if none of that is true we return false 
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used J instead of j (in rankData[j].rank = J;)

```js
var array = [
  {name: 0, dob: ""},
  " ",
  " ",
  " "
];

for(var j=0; j<=4; j++){
if(array[j] !== undefined && array[j] !== " ")
        {
            array[j].rank = j;
        }
}

console.log(array);
```